# Doctype breaking the document (Html5/Css3)

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, doctype

I am building a webpage, and I found a problem which I cannot solve. If I declare the DOCTYPE, the page breaks completely, and if I don't declare it, the IE version won't work properly (the drop down menus won't drop). But, despite of it's broken, if I declare the DOCTYPE, the dropdown menus work at every explorer, including IE. So I really don't know what to do, any idea? I'm currently declaring the DOCTYPE as: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` but I've tried other options and they don't work neither.

Last time I posted here the free server blocked the page (probably too many users, as I'm the only one getting in currently), but these are 2 examples of the page:
with DOCTYPE: http://newfutureuniversity.org/project/
without DOCTYPE (dropdown menus not working with IE9):
http://newfutureuniversity.org/learn/

Any help would be appreciated. Even if it's just to orientate me about where to start searching, as I could't find anything similar.

Comment: Start with http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I already did it, and it gave no important errors at the html nor at the CSS3 (apart of the "missing DOCTYPE" at the one that it's missing it)

Comment: How do you want your page to look like? Could you post some screenshots? I don't see a difference between your two links in my browser (Firefox).

Comment: you are missing the html tags from your working page. This is only allowed in html5 but you are not using an html5 doctype. PS - the `<center>` tag is not part of html5.

Comment: I'm currently working on the pages to improve them, so the first one is not that broken anymore, right now it's just the footer that it's completely gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using or not using the doctype for modern web pages is no longer optional and is required. It is the very first thing that goes down on a page and never changes. If you created a page without one to begin with, then your whole page is set in quirks mode. Trying to fix it or change it by adding/removing the doctype is, essentially, changing the rules and the target as you go along.

Trying to use jQuery to fix this now is just sinking you into a deeper hole. Add the doctype, use a modern browser to get everything how you want it (IE is not a modern browser), then work on getting IE to follow along.

The charset you should be using is `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score -1):

for HTML5 it is nice and small, you have an XHTML declaration

it can simply be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

for HTML 5

Using XHTML tells the parser to be much more strict in what it accepts. you have no `<html>` root in your document (HTML5 won't care about this).

content type specification is different in HTML5 as well

instead of `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />` you can use `<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />` if that is your desired character set.

Comment: Already tried also, and it doesn't work neither...
 I think I'll end up redesigning the broken one if I don't find the solution here, it looks easier and faster

Comment: Yes, and there are a few other things wrong too. Chrome complains about `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. And also, you are using non-HTML5 tags (center). In fact you aren't using any html5 tags at all. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off with xhtml here?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like you have an include for the jQuery file declared

Comment: Okay, thanks. 
About the jQuery, I don't know javascript, there are just 2 small bits that I copied from a tutorial and they worked fine so I just left them. I know it's small and ridiculous, but <input type="email"...> is HTML5, and I'll also work about the center tag, thank you so much

Comment: with HTML5; script tags if generic are assumed javascript, XHTML needs to have a type specification. You can add jQuery directly from their site by adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>` in the head (above your inline script)

Comment: Oh right! it was just that I added it already to the general php included page, but I forgot to add it to that static page (it was just to show the error here), now it's added (:

Comment: you can replace the `<center>` tag with a generic tag and style it to do the same thing with CSS if you want to use HTML5. What are you looking to achieve from an email input? You can work around either problem using either type.

Comment: The login, it's alredy done, I was just saying where my bit of HTML5 was.  
I think I'm finishing to edit the sticky footer with the DOCTYPE, but it's late here so I'll leave it for tomorrow, thank you for your help

Comment: The doctype is not "finicky" in any browser at all and just declaring a XHTML doctype does not make ones page XHTML or change how the browser handles a page. You must serve XHTML as 'application/xhtml+xml' for true XHTML and you aren't doing that. Otherwise it's treated as broken HTML and that's it.